# Laravel 5 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, routes

I am trying to make image uploader in Laravel 5, but I am strill getting this error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219

What can cause this problem?

Form:

```
<form name="upload_image" method="post" action="{{URL::route('uploadImage')}}">
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

routes.php

```
Route::post('uploadImage', [
    'as' => 'uploadImage',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@uploadImage'
]);
```

HomeController.php

```
public function uploadImage() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            $image = Input::get('image');
            $filename  = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $path = public_path('articleImages/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(600, 400)->save($path);
            return view('admin.uploadImage')->with('path', $path);
        }
        return view('/');
    }
    return view('/');
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote, in Laravel 5 just use `route('uploadImage')` not `URL::route('uploadImage')`. As the `URL` factory is deprecated.

Comment: Where did you heard that `UrlGenerator` was deprecated? `URL` is just a facade for that, don't think it will be deprecated...

Comment: I isn`t what is causing this error, i changed it, but still getting the same.

Comment: Is there any route declared in the routes.php file before this one?

Comment: the whole file: http://pastebin.com/chg4p66b

Answer (score 1):

Change URL::route

```
<form name="upload_image" method="post" action="{{route('uploadImage')}}">
```

Comment: I isn`t what is causing this error, i changed it, but still getting the same.

Comment: try changing text to uploadimage instead of uploadImage

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need names for input elements 
like this :

```
<form name="upload_image" method="post" action="{{URL::route('uploadImage')}}">
<input name="image" type="file" accept="image/*">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

2nd thing that you can write the routes like this :

```
Route::post('uploadImage','HomeController@uploadImage');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. With Laravel 5 you have to use `{{ route('uploadImage') }}` instead of `{{URL::route('uploadImage')}}` because Laravel no longer uses URL provider.
2. Have you forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form?